# Top Panel in 20.04 Shrunk After Aug-22-2020 Updates

Tags: gnome-panel

Running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS since April, now at 20.04.1 Behavior just started after updates on 22-Aug-2020. Top Panel is shrunk to about 50% of normal height with contents shrunk proportionately making them very hard to read. Persists after shell restart (v3.36.3) as well as full system reboot. Everything else remains normal sized except for the login prompt on the lock screen which is also shrunk.

If I go to Settings>Displays>Scale and change it to 200%, then hit Apply and then Revert (back to 100% default), everything is back to normal until the next time the shell is restarted, then back to square one...

Appreciate any help!

Thanks!

Comment: It seems a bug that is affecting some people in these days and in different ways but all related to fractional scaling. Me too I'm affected by it. See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269090/ubuntu-20-04-interface-font-too-small-after-restart-even-with-high-scaling-fact and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1268993/ubuntu-20-04-font-and-ui-elements-too-big-on-login I don't know which package(s) may have caused te issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Lorenz. Good to know the issue is not unique to me and is being addressed by developers. At least temporary work-arounds are fairly painless.

Comment: I also have the same issue since about the same time. Tried what you said (change scale to 200% and revert) and it also temporarily fixes the issue for me.

Comment: This issue is fixed for me as soon as Mutter updates were installed on 06-Oct-2020