# Display Text Too large on startup - possible GUI driver issues

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, gui, text

So, I had a few issues installing a fresh Ubuntu 20.04 with respect to the GPU driver. I was having issues with screen size, that were eventually fixed. Now, with a recent update, I have an initial start up and log on screen that is abnormally large. Once I am in the GUI I am faced with a screen with appropriately set sizes (as set in settings), except for text (as seen in the top ribbon in the image below):

[image: Screenshot showing top ribbon]

The large text option in the universal access is not turned on and, strangely, when it is turned on the text resizes back to normal. This isn't a massive problem, as this fixes the issue, but it is a hassle as it has to be done each startup. I suspect it is a driver issue but I don't know where to start. I am new to these forums so, please be kind and let me know what information you need to answer the question. It will be provided promptly.

I did just want to add that it seems the update has affected the mouse as well. Transitions between windows seems to occasionally disable the mouse click momentarily. This is an issue in dragging and dropping, which will occasionally cut out or display unpredictable behaviour. I am fairly certain this isn't an issue with my mouse and the issue emerged just as this update occurred.

Comment: There is a bug in mutter package that causes this trouble. For some users (like me) the problem appears in small fonts, for others in big fonts. Here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1268993/ubuntu-20-04-font-and-ui-elements-too-big-on-login/ and here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269090/ubuntu-20-04-interface-font-too-small-after-restart-even-with-high-scaling-fact some details and workarounds. These are the links for the bugs https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1892440 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1892521

Comment: Thankyou for those links. Unfortunately, none of the solutions on the askubuntu page survived the reboot for me. I saw on the launchpad error, that running       'dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/text-scaling-factor 1.01'
'dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/interface/text-scaling-factor 1.0' would reset the scaling, at least in the GUI. I just have to figure out how to run these commands on startup

Comment: The solutions https://askubuntu.com/a/1269402/1037999 and https://askubuntu.com/a/1269942/1037999 revive at reboot. The first one was implemented by me and I confirm that it works (if you want, yu can increase the sleep time to 1s)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the advice. Unfortunately, the suggestions you posted did not survive startup for me. I had to downgrade libmutter as per https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1892440, comment #17 and this worked a treat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Second Edit:

Quoting from Brian Murray on the launchpad forum for this bug:

"The verification of the Stable Release Update for mutter has completed
successfully and the package is now being released to -updates.
Subsequently, the Ubuntu Stable Release Updates Team is being
unsubscribed and will not receive messages about this bug report.  In
the event that you encounter a regression using the package from
-updates please report a new bug using ubuntu-bug and tag the bug report
regression-update so we can easily find any regressions."

First Edit:

It seems that a fix has come out of the launchpad forums. It has worked for me. Unhold the original hold below, if you did indeed use the below original solution. If not, do not use this command...

`sudo apt-mark unhold libmutter-6-0`

and download/install the package from the PPA as follows...

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ci-train-ppa-service/4265.1`
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt upgrade`

The original answer I gave shall be left here for reference, in case the above is not happy, Jan.

Original:

So, for my machine, it seems that every startup script solution I have tried does not resize the text on the screen, on startup. The only solution that has worked for me has been taken from comment #17 at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mutter/+bug/1892440 and involves downgrading the libmutter package to the state prior to the upgrade. The commands are as follows:

`sudo apt install libmutter-6-0=3.36.1-3ubuntu3 gir1.2-mutter-6=3.36.1-3ubuntu3`
`sudo apt-mark hold libmutter-6-0`

The first command reverts the package and the second command stops subsequent update events from updating the package. The second command is optional, but it means that you will manually either have to unselect this update or re-run the first command untill the problem is fixed with the package.

Comment: how do you "unhold" the package

Comment: @Zany_Zachary1 `sudo apt-mark unhold libmutter-6-0`

Comment: @Zany_Zachary1 I have updated the answer to include some new information on the topic

Comment: The original answer worked for me. Thank you.

Comment: Original answer worked for me. The repo in your updated answer does not have a Release file.

Comment: @ConstiP no worries, they're updating this all the time, so there won't be a static answer here until the fix gets committed to the build, which shouldn't be that far off, now.